# how to switch camera mode to video mode using GPUImage in ios

Tags: camera, video-capture, gpuimage

I am making app like Instagram .i am using GPUImage framework ,in this i have to take photos and videos and share. i able to capture photos using this framework and now i have to capture video but i am struggling how to change camera mode photos to video. any help and tutorial then its very good for me. I used this code camera for photos mode.

```
   if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    self.imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.overlayView.frame = self.imagepicker.cameraOverlayView.frame;
    self.imagepicker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
    self.overlayView = nil;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

           self.imagepicker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    self.imagepicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imagepicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
   // self.imagepicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

}
else{
    self.imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using GPUImage to do both (pictures and videos). Therefore I've created two objects: one of type GPUImageStillCamera(pictures) and other of type GPUImageVideoCamera (videos).

So whenever you need to switch between cameras you basically stop the GPUImageStillCamera capture and initialize a video camera (note that you have to adapt this snippet to your project):

```
 func initializeVideoCamera() {

    // Stop the capture of GPUImageStillCamera
    stillCamera.stopCameraCapture()

    videoCamera = GPUImageVideoCamera.init(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080, cameraPosition: .Back)
    videoCamera?.outputImageOrientation = .Portrait
    videoCamera?.addTarget(filter)

    // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old  movie
    unlink(pathToMovieFile) 

    initializeWriteWithPath(pathToMovieFile)

    videoCamera?.startCameraCapture()
}
```